# Host file redirect for download another file

Tags: 12.04, hosts, redirect

I edited my host file like this.

```
example.com/abc/a.zip example.com/abc/b.ziP
```

So what I need to do is when I enter example.com/abc/a.zip url in browser it should be redirected to example.com/abc/b.zip. But that doesn't work. So where is the fault?

And are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: /etc/hosts file doesn't do redirection. Apache VirtualHosts have a syntax for specifying redirects.

Comment: @muru Could you please tell me how to redirect using apache virtualhosts?

Answer (score 0):

### Remapping URL

If you want to remap `url` to a different location, but clients still access and know original url, you should use `RewriteRule` directive.

Try to add this lines in **VirtualHost** section:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/abc/a\.zip$ /abc/b.ziP [PT]
```

Here is RewriteRule syntax:

```
  RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

where, according to apache [**mod_rewrite manual**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
  Pattern: In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched 
       against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and 
       before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
  Substitution: A DocumentRoot-relative path to the resource to be served. 
       Note that mod_rewrite tries to guess whether you have specified a
       file-system path or a URL-path by checking to see if the first 
       segment of the path exists at the root of the file-system. 
       For example, if you specify a Substitution string of 
       /www/file.html, then this will be treated as a URL-path unless 
       a directory named www exists at the root or your file-system 
       (or, in the case of using rewrites in a .htaccess file, relative 
       to your document root), in which case it will be treated as a 
       file-system path. 
       If you wish other URL-mapping directives (such as Alias) to be 
       applied to the resulting URL-path, use the [PT] flag as described below.
  flag: special action
```

In this case flag value is PT tha means:

```
  passthrough|PT    Forces the resulting URI to be passed back to the URL 
      mapping engine for processing of other URI-to-filename translators, 
      such as Alias or Redirect. details ...
```

[**Here**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html) is useful link with examples.

There is [**Alias**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive that remap content location too. This one is useful if content location is outside of `DocumentRoot`.

### Redirect request

If you want to inform the client that the requested content is located at a different URL, and instruct the client to make a new request with the new URL, you should use [**Redirect**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive.

try adding this line in **VirtualHost** section:

```
  Redirect permanent /abc/a.zip http://example.com/abc/b.ziP
```

This is useful to inform robot that contents are moved in other location, and prevent errors of indexing in search engines.

Answer (score 0):

For simple redirects, the `RewriteEngine` is overkill. Just add this to your site definition:

```
Redirect /abc/a.zip http://example.com/abc/b.zip
```

See [the example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new-extern) in the Apache documentation.